# keeping chome connectable by chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I do a lot of selenium stuff. I can run on my remote server with firefox but installing the firefoxdriver executable is, as I discovered, dangerous to a desktop Ubuntu system. So I set up chromedriver a few months ago and everything worked! Wonderful.

Now here I am:

```
 The chromedriver version (121.0.6167.85) detected in PATH
   at /home/ray/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible
   with the detected chrome version (123.0.6312.58);
   currently, chromedriver 123.0.6312.58 is recommended for
   chrome 123.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in
   PATH and retry
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 ....
```

So, two questions really.

How do I upgrade the chromedriver to the proper version? I see a bunch of docs that say "to be able to connect to chome 115..." and this is not helpful.

Also, will I ALWAYS have the f-ing versions of chrome and chromedriver fighting against each other? Why? Can I just get this installed and then not have something screw with my versions here? What a pain....